# highglight only one row at a time, toggling css class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

if I have rows in a table like this http://output.jsbin.com/icusec/2 where I'm highlighting selected row on a click, how can I improve this to have selected only one, for example if I first select third row it will get highlighted but when I click on second row then second row should become highlighted and third should not.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#rowClick").children("tbody").children("tr").children("td").click(function(){
        $(this.parentNode).toggleClass("active");
    });
});

table, table tr, table tr td {margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; cursor: pointer;}
table tr.active td {background: #ccc;}

<table id="rowClick">
    <tr>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#rowClick").children("tbody").children("tr").children("td").click(function(){
    $('#rowClick tbody tr').removeClass('active')
    $(this.parentNode).toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.active{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="rowClick">
  <tr>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

1. Remove class on all tr then add the class on clicked parent(add selector to be specific to avoid affecting other tr)

Answer (score 3):

Your JavaScript would like something like:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#rowClick").on('click', 'tr', function() {
    $(this)
      .addClass('active')
      .siblings()
          .removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
table,
table tr,
table tr td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
table tr.active td {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="rowClick">
  <tr>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Best of the lot. It would be even better to bind event handler to `tr` element, then there will be no need to use `.parent()`

Comment: True, in OP case yes.

Comment: That is some good technique, i am looking for. Thank you, man.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#rowClick").children("tbody").children("tr").children("td").click(function(){
     $("tr").removeClass("active");
        $(this.parentNode).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

```css
table, table tr, table tr td {margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; cursor: pointer;}
table tr.active td {background: #ccc;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="rowClick">
    <tr>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("td").click(function(){
        $(this).closest("#rowClick").find("tr").removeClass("active");
        $(this.parentNode).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

I hope this will work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution where class can be removed after second click on the same row.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#rowClick tbody tr").click(function(){
      if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
          $(this).removeClass("active");
      }
      else {
        $("#rowClick tbody tr").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
     }
    });
});
```

```css
table, table tr, table tr td {margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; cursor: pointer;}
table tr.active td {background: #ccc;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="rowClick">
    <tr>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: @Satpal My idea is to add possibility to remove class after second click on row